# Two rules between multicols

Tags: rules, multicol

I'd like to add two rules between two columns of a `multicols` environment.

For adding one I used `\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.2pt}` but how can I add two?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can patch the command responsible for typesetting the rule

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol,etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\page@sofar}
  {\vrule\@width\columnseprule}
  {\vrule\@width\columnseprule\kern\doublerulesep\vrule\@width\columnseprule}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.2pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How can I color those vrules, e.g. blue? Difficult?

Comment: `\columnseprulecolor` dictates the color.  See [documentation](http://mirror.math.ku.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/tools/multicol.pdf).

Comment: @KeksDose `\renewcommand{\columnseprulecolor}{\color{blue}}`

Comment: Sorry, RTFM, yes. But thank you both, egreg and cslstr. Looks cool. Take a kind of purple color (+xcolor-package) and the layout reminds me on centuries old books.